# REGEX cannot read property '0' of null but it works with console.log()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm fetching a srcset with a bunch of images URLs, and I'm trying to get just the first URL.

I thought it would be a great idea to use a REGEX and just get the string that matches "https:// (everything between) .jpg", so I did this code:

```
let imageURL;
if (banner_image) {
imageURL = banner_image.children[0].srcset.match(/https:(.*?).jpg/)[0]
}
```

when I console.log this with the zero at the end `.match(/https:(.*?).jpg/)[0]` I get an error `property '0' of null`. But then when I do it without the [0] I get an array with these properties:

```
[0: "https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg",
1: "//res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large",
groups: undefined,
index: 0,
input: "https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1600,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1600w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1366,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1366w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1024,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1024w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_768,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 768w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_640,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_460,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 460w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_300,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 300w",
length: 0]
```

I expected the output to be only the first URL as a string. 'https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg'

I think that regex is completely working, but i can't get it just because of the [0]

**SOLUTION:**
I didn't have the while statement for the REGEX. Here is the code.

```
let regex = /https:(.*?).jpg/gm;
let arr;
let imageURL;

if (banner_image) {

   let str = banner_image.children[0].children[0].children[1].srcset
   while ((arr = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
      imageURL = arr[0]
   }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a sample definition for `banner_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to design an expression that'd be somewhat similar to:

```
https?:\/\/[\w._-]*\/(?:[\w._-]*\/[\w._-]*)*\.jpe?g
```

not sure though.

```js
const regex = /https?:\/\/[\w._-]*\/(?:[\w._-]*\/[\w._-]*)*\.jpe?g/gm;
const str = `[0: "https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg",
1: "//res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large",
groups: undefined,
index: 0,
input: "https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1920,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1920w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1600,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1600w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1366,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1366w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_1024,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 1024w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_768,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 768w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_640,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 640w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_460,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 460w, https://res.cloudinary.com/doordash/image/fetch/q_auto:eco,f_auto,w_300,c_fill,ar_100:55/https://doordash-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/photos/58c72a24-9293-40bd-867d-56603d7a686e-retina-large.jpg 300w",
length: 0]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your Regex doesn't contain `g` flag, `String.prototype.match` returns the same as `Regex.exec`. Now here is its definition found on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value):

> If the match fails, the exec() method returns null

This means `banner_image.children[0].srcset` changed in between your tries and the regex returned `null` due to a mismatch

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthetical that matched containing the text that was captured.

That's what you got after a good match